# Type-Hinting Child class returning self

Tags: python, abstract-class, type-hinting, abc

Is there any way to type an abstract parent class method such that the child class method is known to return itself, instead of the abstract parent.

```py
class Parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self) -> [what to hint here]:
        pass

class Child1(Parent)
    def method(self):
        pass

    def other_method(self):
        pass

class GrandChild1(Child1)
    def other_method_2(self):
        pass
```

This is more to improve autocompletes for IDEs like PyCharm or VScode's python plugin.

Comment: @MadPhysicist that's not really relevant here, abstractmethods needs to use `pass` or `...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Wow. I forgot that part by the time I read as far as the pass. Time to get some sleep this week I guess.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, the general approach is described in the docs [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#annotating-instance-and-class-methods)

```
import typing
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound='Parent') # use string

class Parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self: T) -> T:
        ...

class Child1(Parent):
    def method(self: T) -> T:
        return self

    def other_method(self):
        pass

class GrandChild1(Child1):
    def other_method_2(self):
        pass

reveal_type(Child1().method())
reveal_type(GrandChild1().method())
```

And `mypy` gives us:

```
test_typing.py:22: note: Revealed type is 'test_typing.Child1*'
test_typing.py:23: note: Revealed type is 'test_typing.GrandChild1*'
```

Note, I had to keep using type-variables to get this to work, so when I originally tried to use the actual child class in the child class annotation, it (erroneously?) inherited the type in the grandchild:

```
class Child1(Parent):
    def method(self) -> Child1:
        return self
```

I'd get with mypy:

```
test_typing.py:22: note: Revealed type is 'test_typing.Child1'
test_typing.py:23: note: Revealed type is 'test_typing.Child1'
```

Again, I am not sure if this is expected/correct behavior. The [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self) currently has a warning:

> This feature is experimental. Checking code with type annotations for
>   self arguments is still not fully implemented. Mypy may disallow valid
>   code or allow unsafe code.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.11 introduced more elegant solution based on [PEP-0673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/), predefined type `Self` ([official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self)). Example:

```
from typing import Self

class Parent(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def method(self) -> Self:
        pass

class Child1(Parent)
    def method(self) -> Self:
        pass

    def other_method(self) -> Self:
        pass

class GrandChild1(Child1)
    def other_method_2(self) -> Self:
        pass
```

It covers [classmethods](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/#use-in-classmethod-signatures) too:

```
class Shape:
    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config: dict[str, float]) -> Self:
        return cls(config["scale"])
```

NOTE: for pre-python-3.11 one can use:

1 - Quoted type, e.g.

```
class Parent:
    def method(self) -> "Parent":
        pass
```

2 - or postoponed type hint evaluation ([PEP-0563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/), or other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544901/565525), python 3.7+):

```
from __future__ import annotations
class Parent:
    def method(self) -> Parent:
        pass
```

3 - or install external package [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) ([latest dox](https://typing-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)) - which enables older Python versions using typing features from future Python versions. [Self (first solution, Python 3.11+)](https://typing-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#Self) is also supported.