# from __future__ import annotations

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

[Python doc `__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html)

In python doc about `__future__` there is a table below where it shows that
annotations "optional in" 3.7.0b1 and "mandatory in" 4.0
but I am still able to use annotations in 3.8.2 without importing annotations then what is the use of it.

```
>>> def add_int(a:int, b:int) -> int:
...     return a + b
>>> add_int.__annotations__
{'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'int'>}
```

I doubt I don't clearly understand the meaning of "optional in" and "mandatory in" here

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Mandatory is an interesting word choice. I guess it means that it's by default in the language. You don't have to enable it with `from __future__ import annotations`

The `annotations` feature are referring to the PEP 563: **Postponed** evaluation of annotations. It's an enhancement to the existing [annotations feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) which was initially introduced in python 3.0 and redefined as [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) in python 3.5, that's why your code works under python 3.8.

Here's what optional `from __future__ import annotations` changes in python 3.7+:

```
class A:
    def f(self) -> A: # NameError: name 'A' is not defined
        pass
```

but this works

```
from __future__ import annotations

class A:
    def f(self) -> A:
        pass
```

See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations) chapter in python 3.7 what's new about postponed annotations:

> Since this change breaks compatibility, the new behavior needs to be enabled on a per-module basis in Python 3.7 using a `__future__` import:
>
> `from __future__ import annotations`
>
> It will become the default in Python <strike>3.10</strike>*.

* it was announced to be default in 3.10 (when python3.7 was released), but it was now moved to a later release

Comment: it didn't completely answered my question "Optional in" and why my code working without importing annotations from __future__

Comment: bc function __ annotations __ (dunder) were introduced in Python 3.0 per PEP 3107. (cf. bit.ly/python-annotations). 
Subsequent PEPs added type hints (3.5), updated syntax (3.6) changed evaluation time (3.7) and restricted annotation semantics to type hinting (3.8). HTH.

Comment: `from __future__ import annotations` will not be default in Python 3.10, but in a posterior version: https://dev.to/tiangolo/the-future-of-fastapi-and-pydantic-is-bright-3pbm (see "What's Next" section).

Comment: This import also allows you to use `|` to define union types in earlier versions.

Comment: I have a problem with "SyntaxError: future feature annotations is not defined". How to solve it?

Comment: @Land it requires python 3.7+, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889746/cant-import-annotations-from-future

Comment: I think it will be implemented in Python3.12 using lazyimports (not sure though)

Comment: I expect the word "Mandatory" was used because Python is really just an standard/interface definition, though most people think of "Python" as referring to CPython

Answer (score 16):

Mandatory as in coming by default.
Optional as in needed to be "activated" from an `from __future__ import annotations` statement

Answer (score 11):

The first part is easy: You can use annotations because annotations have existed since Python 3.0, you don't need to import anything from `__future__` to use them

What you're importing if you do `from __future__ import annotations` is *postponed* annotations. The postponed annotations feature means that you can use something in an annotation even if it hasn't been defined yet

Try the following:

```
def get_a_pineapple() -> Pineapple:
    fresh_pineapple = Pineapple()
    return fresh_pineapple

class Pineapple:
    pass

print("....whatever you want to print")
```

If you try to run that script, you'll get `NameError: name 'Pineapple' is not defined`

There's three easy things you could do to get rid of the NameError:

1. Take out the  `-> Pineapple` type hint. This works, which shows that the annotation/type-hint is part of the problem
2. Move the class definition up, so that it happens before the function definition. This also works, which shows that the order makes a difference
3. replace the hint  `-> Pineapple` with  `-> "Pineapple"`. (This one isn't very relevant to the question, but it is a valid option that works with most type-checking tools)
4. Import `__future__.annotations`. This also works, because it changes the rules, and the order no longer makes a difference

Number (2) is probably the most interesting one, because it shows what the normal rules are for Python 3: if you use a name as a type hint, then that name has to already be defined *before* the type hint. And number (4) shows the purpose of importing `__future__.annotations`: it changes that rule

(As for 'mandatory in 4.0' I think it means that postponed annotations is going to become a mandatory feature for python 4.0 interpreters. ie if someone is writing a python 4.0 interpreter, then it's mandatory to give it this feature)

Comment: How far does it postpone it? Say I have a `main.py` file that imports both a `fruits.py` file containing the definition of `Pineapple` and another file containing your example `get_pineapple`. Would your example still work? I wouldn't want that last file to have `from fruits import Pineapple` just for the sake of type-hinting, and also because it's an extra risk of cyclical imports.

Comment: From some playing around, I think it's deferred forever. I tried deleting the definition of Pineapple entirely, and I still didn't get an error. (You would get an error if you deleted the definition and then tried to actually call the function, but that's because the first line of the function is trying to create a `Pineapple()` object, not because of the  typehint)

Comment: re the imports: it seems like you can `Pineapple` as an annotation without ever defining or importing it. So if you just want a human-readable annotation, then you can use it without importing anything. But if that's all you want, then you could use a comment. A lot of the point of annotations is to let you use a typechecker, and your typechecker will need to know what a `Pineapple` is in this context. If that name isn't defined or imported anywhere in this script, then the typechecker won't know what you're talking about. So realistically, yes you still have to import the name