# Referencing other objects of same class in a method of a class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, methods

I am new to programming and learning Python. Right now I am trying to figure out howto write a value to another object of the same class inside of a method definition inside the class. I mean something like this:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, attribute, lst = True):
    self.attribute = attribute
    if lst is True:
        self.lst = []

    def add_amount(self, amount):
        self.lst.append(dict(Amount = amount))

    def total:
        self.total = []
        for each in self.lst:
            self.total.append(each.get("Amount"))
        self.total = sum(self.total)

    #def transfer(self, amount, attribute):
        #here I would like to be able to add
        #a value (for example self.total) to
        #the lst [] of a different instance of
        #this class

firstInstance = myClass("First")
secondInstance = myClass("Second")

firstInstance.add_amount(10)
firstInstance.add_amount(20)
  
##firstInstance.transfer(15, "Second")

#How can I write the transfer
#function so that it will add
#the value of the first argument 
#to the empty list of the instance
#object with the attribute "Second" 
#(in this case secondInstance)?
```

How do I have to program that? I hope I explained my problem in an understandable way, hope you guys can help me! Thanks in advance! :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass the `secondInstance` as an argument to your `transfer` function. You could potentially do something like this:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self, attribute, lst = True):
    self.attribute = attribute
    if lst is True:
        self.lst = []

    def add_amount(self, amount):
        self.lst.append(dict(Amount = amount))

    def subract_amount(self, amount):
        # TODO
        pass

    def total:
        self.total = []
        for each in self.lst:
            self.total.append(each.get("Amount"))
        self.total = sum(self.total)

    def transfer(self, amount, other):
        self.subtract_amount(amount)
        other.add_amount(amount)


firstInstance = myClass("First")
secondInstance = myClass("Second")

firstInstance.add_amount(10)
firstInstance.add_amount(20)
  
firstInstance.transfer(15, secondInstance)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer and sorry for replying so late! The way you suggested works, but I was trying to put the actual attribute name (i.e.if I want to transfer from "Clothing" to "Tools", I wanted to put the attribute name of "Tools" in the method as an argument) of the object I want to transfer to in the method as an argument, and not the object name itself. If you cannot do it that way though, I will just name the objects correspondingly. Is there a way to do it like I imagined to do it before? Thanks again, really appreciate you guys taking your time to answer questions!

Comment: The way you suggested is possible. I'd suggest looking into the Mediator Design Pattern to implement what you want. Here is an example: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/mediator/python/example 
Think about simply building a myClassMediator class that handles all your myClass instances. The myClassMediator manager will be able to keep track of each instance internally.

Comment: Can you also tell how to do type annotation for `other` argument?

Comment: @JatinVerma Would need to `from __future__ import annotations`. Specify `other: myClass`. See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544854/from-future-import-annotations