# How to use python typing with types that are not declared at the point in file?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a problem with python type annotations when a type is not declared at the point in file. Especially I have the problem when a class has a function that returns an instance of the class:

```
class Foo:
    def clone(self) -> Foo:
        return Foo()
```

results at runtime (not when checking with mypy) in an error:

```
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Add at the beginning of the file the line

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544854/from-future-import-annotations) for a related question.

Comment: I wonder if it's better to use `__future__` or strings. But why does python itself evaluate the annotations anyway? I am confused, why the linter doesn't have the problem and the interpreter, which should ignore the annotations, raises an exception.

Comment: This is a great question. Here you have the long answer: 
https://adamj.eu/tech/2021/05/15/python-type-hints-future-annotations/

The short answer is that, ignoring compatibility issues between python versions, it is better using types insted of strings. Why? Because turning them into strings is a workaround, you could put any stuff inside the string and you would now get an error. Python evaluates the type hints to assure they exist. There a deeper reasons that I won't tell in a comment. If you are curious read the link a attached.