# How to include instances of a given class in its constructor in python?

Tags: python

How do we include instances of a given class in its constructor?

```
class Node:
  # Results in "Unresolved reference 'Node'"
  def __init__(self, val: int, left: Node, right: Node):
           self.val = val
           self.left = left
           self.right = right
```

Note: I have seen several questions *similar* to this but they are not asking exactly the same thing and/or are garbled.

**Update**  Not surprisingly there does exist an answer somewhere in SOF to the question. But given the question I posed it's basically impossible to find that Q&A from *This question already has answers here* .  The answer given in a comment below is

```
from __future_ import annotations
```

as the first line in the script/module

Comment: Import `annotations` from `__future__`?

Comment: yes that's what I was looking for. pls make an answer

Comment: I think most is said already here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544901/20599896. ;) But happy to help, anyway.

Comment: It's basically impossible to find that Q&A mentioned above _This question already has answers here_ when looking for an answer to the question I posed.