# Removing Python 3.10+ type hints for Python 3.8 runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, python-typing, google-cloud-composer

I have a codebase that was developed using Python 3.10 and was originally designed to run on a that version of Python. However, we have migrated to use Google Cloud Composer, which only supports Python 3.8.12.

The main issue I am running into is that our codebase uses a lot of the newer typing syntax and features that are only available on 3.10+ such as the new union syntax. Is there anyway to remove all type hints from our code?

Here is a sample function showcasing some of the issues:

```py
    def sampleFunction(
        self,
        argument1: bool,
        argument2: str,
        argument3: float,
    ) -> dict[str, list[float]]:
        var1: bool = True
        var2: str = "Hello"
```

There are thousands of lines of code in this codebase, and it would be impossible to remove it all by hand. I've tried writing a quick script using Python's AST package to remove all type hints, but it doesn't really work. Specifically, it removes the type hints around function arguments and returns, but not for variable declarations.

```py
class TypeHintRemover(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def recursive(func):
        """decorator to make visitor work recursive"""

        def wrapper(self, node):
            self.generic_visit(node)
            return func(self, node)

        return wrapper

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        # remove the return type definition
        node.returns = None
        # remove all argument annotations
        if node.args.args:
            for arg in node.args.args:
                arg.annotation = None

        return node

    def visit_Assign(self, node):
        for target in node.targets:
            if hasattr(target, "type_comment") and target.type_comment:
                target.type_comment = None
        return node

    def visit_Attribute(self, node: Attribute) -> Any:
        if hasattr(node, "type_comment") and node.type_comment:
            node.type_comment = None
        return node

    @recursive
    def visit(self, node):
        return super().visit(node)
```

Comment: Looks like you missed `visit_AnnAssign`. You're removing the type comments on un-annotated assignments, rather than removing annotations. (Variable annotations without an actual assignment are still `AnnAssign`, by the way.)

Comment: Don't do this: just add `from __future__ import annotations` to the top of all files (`ruff` or `isort` can do it for you). This will allow almost all typing usages except those in `cast`, but these should be trivial to resolve manually by stringifying like `cast("int | str", foo)` - everything in annotations (arguments, return types and variable annotations) will be treated as a simple string. This may break if you use annotations at runtime (you probably don't), but is the most practical solution otherwise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544854/from-future-import-annotations