# Python type hint parameter superclass's instance but not subclass's instance

Tags: python, class, instance, mypy, type-hinting

I have the following python class

```py
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls, baz):
        pass

class Egg(Foo):
    pass


egg = Egg()
egg.bar(Foo())
```

I want to type hint the baz parameter so that it accept **only** the instance of Foo not the subclass, for example Egg.

```py
from typing import Self

    ...
    def bar(cls, baz: Self):
        ...
```

But when i use mypy to static type check, it complain `Argument 1 to "bar" of "Foo" has incompatible type "Foo"; expected "Egg"  [arg-type]`

I know the `Self` is for the instance type, but i don't know why it don't accept the instance of it's superclass. I have read this question [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class), but it allow the subclass instance and not the superclass instance.

I try to fix it with `def bar(cls, baz: Foo):`, but the linter complain `undefined name 'Foo'`. Any idea to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Edit: is there a better way than use of class string for example `def bar(cls, baz: "Foo"):`

Comment: Can you try `baz: 'Foo'`?

Comment: What Python version you're using?

Comment: You can use [`from __future__ import annotations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544854/from-future-import-annotations) instead of strings to annotate before/during defintion.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych yes i tried it, is there a better approach?

Comment: @matszwecja my python version is 3.12

Comment: @ivvija it solve the problem. Can you add your comment as answer so that i can accept that

Comment: Your question is a dupe of [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class). So I flagged it as such.

Comment: Yes it's answer the question. I don't know the meaning of `annotations` before.