How can I use type hints to declare an instance method of a class accepts another class instance as a parameter?
How can I write a class in Python that has a method with an argument that should be an instance of the class?
class MyClass:
    def compare(self, other: MyClass):
        pass

This gives me an error:
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined


Try using annotations package, described here.
Change your code to the following:
from __future__ import annotations

class MyClass:
    def compare(self, other: MyClass):
        pass

Also, there is a helpful tutorial here.

Interesting find! I never knew __future__ had annotations -- and by all accounts, this is quite current. Another SO answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544901/1033027) goes into some detail about it. This appears to be the correct way to do it, since using the Self type (PEP 673) is inappropriate here, and TypeVar['MyClass'] — which has sometimes been used like this in the past — semantically makes less sense.

annotations is actually quite old, first introduced in Python 3.7. The original idea to make it mandatory was abandoned, with work on its replacement still on-going.
