# How can I make a property with returning of Self for inheritance Python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, typechecking, python-3.10

I have a similar structure

```py
class Base:
   id: int

   @property
   def parent(self) -> Base:
      return get_parent_by_id(self.id)

class Result(Base):
   answer: str


result = Result()
print(result.parent.answer)
```

The property `parent` is `Result`, but type checking calc this as `Base`. How can I change type hints of this code for to get an object of current class?

`@classmethod` lose link to an object. `from typing import Self` available from the version 3.11. `@abstractmethod` ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58986031/type-hinting-child-class-returning-self)) requires an implementation the field in each inherit class.

Comment: I found resolve
```@classmethod def get(cls: Type[T], id: int) -> T: return get_object_by_id(id)```
and I removed type hint for the ```parent``` property